# I got error updating database. Cause: java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException

Tags: spring, mybatis

[my code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wrPlr.png)

[error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7gDSK.png)i.stack.imgur.com/4T1Jl.png

I got Error updating database. Cause  java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException. The database, [{orderProductQty=3, productCd=4}, {orderProductQty=2, productCd=1}], sent from Service to Dao. but the data's not updating in Mybatis. I don't know the reason why.. so I tried to fixed many times like below. but it's the same.
1, 
2,
3. 
4, 
5.

Comment: send the parameter notetitle in you post.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [MissingServletRequestParameterException](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45683153/missingservletrequestparameterexception)

Comment: @pringi I've just given require = false , defaultValue = "defaultNotetitle", like somethings but it's the same. I had no idea how to fix...

Comment: http://localhost:8080/note/save?notetitle=A&notedescription=B. You see a tutorial over spring web like https://spring.io/guides/gs/serving-web-content/

Comment: It's a bad idea to use query parameters for your save method. As you already use a POST request it's better to pass an object to the server using `ModelAttribute`.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to change @RequestParam("notetitle") String notetitle to

@RequestParam(name="notetitle) String notetitle.

Comment: Both are the same